# Trino UNNEST fields throwing TrinoQueryError (type=INTERNAL_ERROR, name=PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR)

Tags: hive, google-bigquery, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I'm trying to unnest two fields in Trino and it throws the below error after running the query for around 30 minutes. The source table has only around 3k records, and the fields I'm trying to unnest has many child elements and is of the type row. Below is the glimpse of the error.

```
16:58:28  Runtime Error in model indirect_comm_blah (models/sdm/indirect_comm_blah.sql)
16:58:28    TrinoQueryError(type=INTERNAL_ERROR, name=PAGE_TRANSPORT_ERROR, message="Error fetching http://172.22.xx.xx:8080/v1/task/20220618_164136_00199_pkifc.1.1.0/results/0/0: Expected response code to be 200, but was 503:
```

Below is my query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM hosting_ssl ssl,
    UNNEST(main_array) as main_extract,
    UNNEST (sub_array) AS sub_extract
```

The fields `main_array` and `sub_array` are of type:

```
main_array : array(row(col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 varchar, col4 varchar, col5 boolean))

sub_array : array(row(col_a varchar, col_b varchar, col_c varchar, col_d varchar, col_e boolean, col_f varchar, col_g varchar, col_h varchar, col_i integer, col_j varchar, col_k varchar, col_l varchar, col_m varchar, col_n varchar, col_o varchar, col_p array(varchar)))
```

I also noticed that instead of selecting all fields in the cte, avoid selecting the fields main_array and sub_array gives the output quick. Is this happening because of the type of the fields `main_array` and `sub_array` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying explicitly `CROSS JOIN` to perform join with unnested data:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM hosting_ssl ssl
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(main_array) as main_extract(me),
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sub_array) AS sub_extract(se)
```

Comment: When we write ```SELECT * FROM hosting_ssl ssl,
    UNNEST(main_array) as main_extract,
    UNNEST (sub_array) AS sub_extract``` , isn't CROSS JOIN inferred implicitly ?

Comment: @JohnThomas yes, it seems so. It seems that I caught some corner case when the engine was not able to process the test request.